# flask-SQLAlchemy + postgres unique constraint error

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to achieve this two points right here:

1.- sort users by his bestfriend name 
2.- sort users by his number of friend

this is what i wrote:

```
class Monkey(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'monkey'
    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint('best_friend'),
    )

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True)
    best_friend = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('monkey.name'))
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    number_friends = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, name, age, email, password, best_friend=None, is_admin=False):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.email = email
        self.password = generate_password_hash(password)
        self.best_friend = best_friend
        self.is_admin = is_admin

    def number_friends(self):
        number = Friendship.query.filter_by(monkey=self.id).count()
        return number

    def get_best_friend(self):
        bf = Monkey.query.filter_by(id=self.best_friend).first()
        return bf.name

    def is_friend_of(self, friend):
        friendship = Friendship.query.filter_by(monkey=self.id, friend=friend).first()
        if (friendship == None):
            return False
        else:
            return True



class Friendship(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'friendship'
    __table_args__ = (
        db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('monkey', 'friend'),
    )

    monkey = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('monkey.id'))
    friend = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('monkey.id'))

    def __init__(self, monkey, friend):
        self.monkey = monkey
        self.friend = friend
```

so, as you can see i can get the number of friends from a monkey by using the method `number_friends()`, the problem is that i cant figure out how to use this number to order the query

what can i do?

here is what i already tried

```
monkeys = models.Monkey.query.order_by(models.Monkey.number_friends()).paginate(page, 5, False)
```

so far i know this doesnt help because i have to make an instantiation to use this method right? is there a way to order the query the way i want with sqlalchemy using this method `number_friends()` ?